# Proving pathwise independence of integral of f along any path is equivalent to Cauchy's integral theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be analytic and $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ be two arbitrary closed paths. Prove that:
>
> $ \int_{\gamma} f(z) \ dz = 0$ for any closed path $ \iff\int_{\gamma_1} f(z) \ dz = \int_{\gamma_2} f(z) \ dz $.

It's easy to see the $\implies$ direction, but I'm having a harder time with the other.

Comment: Take the $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ from the right side. Can you see that $\gamma_1 - \gamma_2$ forms a closed path?

Comment: @Kezer, yes, but can any closed path be written like that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread, I didn't see that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are arbitrary closed paths. I assume your $U$ is supposed to be open? Then, choose some circle with its disc fully contained in $U$ - Cauchy makes the contour integral $0$. It's a closed path, so all integrals for closed paths equal $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Kezer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the question actually is: to prove that $\displaystyle\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=0$ for any closed path if and only if for any two paths $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ with the same initial points and the same final points, $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)\,\mathrm dz$.

If the second condition holds, let $\gamma$ be a closed path. And let $\gamma^\star\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ be the constant path such that $\gamma^\star(t)$ is equal to the initial (and final) point of $\gamma$. Then$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_{\gamma^*}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=0.$$

Comment: Why am I allowed to take the path $\gamma^{*}$?

Comment: @MatheusAndrade I don't understand your question. If $[a,b]$ is the domain of $\gamma$ and if $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)=z$, then I defined $\gamma^\star (t)=z$. That's all.

Comment: It was a stupid question. Thanks anyway. I see what I missed now.